# How to export a model and armature into another blender project?

Tags: animation, armature, export, import

I don't know how to properly export a model and armature into another project and still be able to animate with it in the new project.

Comment: You could use "append" File > Append

Comment: you can also open 2 blender files, activate the Copy Attributes addon and copy paste from a blend to another

Comment: Where are two ways of doing it. You can either copy a model and armature, or make a library link between files. First is easier, second lets synchronize changes between files. What are you looking for?